# Prevent datagrid edit from updating more than one record at a time in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, datagrid, records

I have an ASP.NET datagrid but the issue is that I go to edit a column for one record and it ends up updating all records shown from the database for any column that I update (even the ones not selected).  Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I had to also return the Primary Key unique ID from the returned records and then say to only update WHERE id = @ID